# date: extra operand %d' error

Tags: shell, date, awk

I have a text log file, the format is like the following

```
Thread-28689296: Thu Aug 25 15:18:41 2016 [ info ]: xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx
```

So I want to run cron job to find some certain error messages in last a few minutes. I wrote the following command

```
awk -vDate=`date +%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y` -vDate2=`date --date="2 minutes ago" +%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y` '$5 > Date && $5 < Date2' /var/log/dummy.log  | grep "Fatal"
```

In the above command, i search for messages that have a timestamp beween time now and 2 minutes ago with a string `Fatal`.

But I got the following error

```
date: extra operand %d'
Try date --help' for more information.
date: extra operand %d'
Try date --help' for more information.
```

If I run date commands, I got the results as the following

```
date "+%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"
Aug 25 15:25:01 2016

date --date="2 minutes ago" +"%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y" 
Aug 25 15:31:42 2016
```

So the date commands in my awk script should be okay.

I also want to redirect the found error messages happening 2 minutes to a file to mail as alert but I did not get that far yet.

Please kindly advice me what is wrong in my awk script. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why on earth would you complicate this with cron?  Here's an idea; use cron to extract all the log entries since you last ran cron, and then put those entries into a single file.  Call it the "log copy"! Seriously, if what you want is to get an email alert within two minutes of a log entry, don't use cron.  Instead, have the logs routed through a daemon (eg, syslog-ng) that makes the log entry and sends you an email alert.

Comment: The logs are not in standard syslog so I can not use syslog-ng.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here is with `date` itself. Let's see how.

You are saying:

```
vDate2=`date --date="2 minutes ago" +%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y`
```

Because you want to use

```
date --date="2 minutes ago" +%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y
```

However, if you try to run it you'll see that you get the error:

> date: extra operand ‘%d’
>   Try 'date --help' for more information.

The problem is that you need to enclose the FORMAT controls within double quotes:

```
#                             v                  v
$ date --date="2 minutes ago" "+%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"
Aug 25 14:49:31 2016
```

When this is done, all together your full `awk` one-liner can be:

```
awk -v Date="$(date "+%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")" \
    -v Date2="$(date --date="2 minutes ago" "+%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")" \
     '$5 > Date && $5 < Date2' file
```

Note I am using `-v Date="$(date ...)"`:

- `$( )` for process substitution, since [backticks ` are almost deprecated, ir at least considered legacy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126928/40596).
- `date=" things "` to prevent errors if the content has spaces.
- `v var=value` using spaces after `-v`, since `-vvar=value` is gawk-specific.

Comment: Right. Also by using `-vDate=...` without a space after the `-v` your script is gawk-specific and since it's gawk-specific you don't need the external calls to `date` at all, you can just use gawks builtin time functions: `awk 'BEGIN{fmt="%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"; Date=strftime(fmt); Date2=strftime(fmt,systime()-120)} $5 > Date && $5 < Date2' file`.

Comment: Oops, didn't see your answer!

Comment: Yes, the line -v Date="$(date "+%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")" resolves the errror "extra operand". Thanks. But I still have a problem with my condition  "$5 > Date && $5 < Date2". If the log data is "Thread-28689296: Thu Aug 25 15:18:41 2016 xxxx", the value of $5 is actually 18 (the minute in the log timestamp). I want to get values between 18 and 16 of values from variable Date and date2. The comparason is not correct so i just want to compare the minutes only. How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ShuqinLi-Kokko please update your question with some relevant data so I can test with it. Otherwise, I cannot help you.

Comment: Hi fedorqui, thanks for your help. For example, I have the following line of log entries in my log file: Thread-28689296: Thu Aug 25 15:18:41 2016 [ info ]: abcd efddf Thu Aug 25 15:19:01 2016 [ info ]: xvbdfdre dfdfd Thu Aug 25 15:19:11 2016 [ info ]: Fatal error Thu Aug 25 15:19:41 2016 [ info ]: dfdfdfd. If now time is Aug 25 15:19:41 2016, I want to find between 15:19:41 and 15:17:41 those lines that have "Fatal error" in my log file.     So the current time should be from date and x minutes ago should from "date "x minutes ago" to find certain error messages from the application log.

Comment: @ShuqinLi-Kokko as I said, you need to update your questions with this data. I cannot reproduce anything with data given in comments, since the format is lost.