# Shell script having problems

Tags: linux, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ true ]
do
    echo "$(top -b -o +%MEM -n 1 | head -n +8 | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $12";"$10 }');$(date +'%H:%M:%S')" >> RAM.csv
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then 
        sleep 1m
    else 
        sleep "$1"
    fi
done
```

ERROR OUTPUT : date: extra operand '%H:%M:%S'
what is wrong with this?

Comment: probably something to do with the double quotation marks `"`

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with the line. The quoting is correct. How do you execute this script?

Comment: I saved this as RAM.sh and I run it in Linux with fedora iso using the command ./RAM.sh and the output is the error output I have typed on top

Comment: Does this answer your question? [date: extra operand %d' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145550/date-extra-operand-d-error)

Answer (score 0):

Below you find a mildly improved version of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# All output is appended to RAM.csv
exec >> RAM.csv

# Do an infinite loop
while :; do
   # Get command with most used memory, print it in CSV format, append time
   date "+$(ps -eo ucmd -o '%mem' --sort=-%mem h | awk -v OFS=";" '($1=$1);{exit}');%T"
   # sleep $1 seconds, if not defined 1m
   sleep "${1:-1m}"
done
```